# Prove that in case of a skew-symmetric matrix, $A$, we have, $A^t=-A$.

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, proof-explanation, skew-symmetric-matrices

I cam accross the following definition in Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix , which is attached below , for a reference:[image]

However, I dont get how the two definitions i.e one focussing upon the property $A^t=A$ and another giving a condition upon the elements $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$ are equivalent. I don't get how those two conditions given , are equivalent to one another ?

My understanding behind this fact goes as follows:

> If $A=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}$, then $A^t=(b_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}$, where $b_{ij}=a_{ji}$, so, $A^t=(b_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}=(a_{ji})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}$. Now,if $A=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}=(a_{ij})$, then $A^t=(a_{ji})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}=(a_{ji})$ and hence if $-A^t=A$, then $(-A^t=)(-a_{ji})=(A=)(a{ij})$ or $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$.So we can say, if , $-A^t=A$ then $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$. Now, conversely if $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$ then it follows trivially that $-A^t=A$. So, we can say $-A^t=A$ iff  $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$.

Is my understanding of the proof correct?

Comment: We say that $A=B$ **iff** $[A]_{ij} = [B]_{ij}$ for all $i,j$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you! But I dont get what's that supposed to imply in this context?

Comment: $B=A^T$ **iff** $B_{ij} = A_{ji}$ and $C=-B$ **iff** $C_{ij} = -B_{ij}$. Combining, we see that $A= -A^T$ **iff** $A_{ij} = - A_{ji}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Well, if,  $A=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}$,  then $A^t=(b_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}$,where $b_{ij}=a_{ji}$ so,  $$A^t=(b_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}=(a_{ji})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}$$. Now,if $A=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}=(a_{ij})$,  then $A^t=(a_{ji})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}=(a_{ji})$, and hence if $-A^t=A$, then $(-A^t=)(-a_{ji})=(A=)(a{ij})$ or $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$. So, we can say, if $-A^t=A$, then, $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$. Now, conversely, if $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$, then it follows trivially that $-A^t=A$. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

Just write the matrices in terms of their entries. Recall that if

$$A = (a_{i,j})_{1 \le i \le m, 1 \le j \le n}$$

then the transpose is given by

$$A^{\mathsf{T}} = (a_{j,i})_{1 \le j \le n, 1 \le i \le m}$$

Hence, if $A^{\mathsf{T}} = -A$ then

$$a_{j,i} = - a_{i,j} \text{ for all } i \in \{1,2,\cdots,m\}, j \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$$

(that is, corresponding entries in each position are equal).

---

In particular, owing to the ranges in which $i,j$ are defined, we automatically know that $A$ is square if this condition is satisfied (it needs to be the "same shape" before and after) so we can write (in a less cumbersome manner)

$$A = (a_{i,j})_{1\le i,j \le m} \qquad A^{\mathsf{T}} = (a_{j,i})_{1\le i,j \le m}$$

and hence $A^{\mathsf{T}} = -A$ if and only if

$$a_{j,i} = - a_{i,j} \text{ for all } i,j \in \{1,2,\cdots,m\}$$

Comment: Thank you! I see it now. But if $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$ , then, can we still say $A=-A^t$?...

Comment: If you have it for all $i,j$ and the matrix is square, then yes

Comment: Thank you! But I think your post needs a slight modification,  as if $A=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq m, 1\leq j\leq n}$, then $A^t=(b_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j\leq m}$, where $b_{ij}=a_{ji}$, I think this is a more precise way of defining transposed matrices ...(maybe somewhat of a simpler definition , atleast to me)...

Comment: @PrincessEve But what if it's not a square matrix, then why wouldn't it hold true?...

Comment: Try taking the transpose of a non-square matrix and you'll immediately see why -- they don't have the same dimensions

Comment: Thank you! I do get it now. But I think if $A=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}$,  then $A^t=(b_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}$,where $b_{ij}=a_{ji}$ so,  $$A^t=(b_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}=(a_{ji})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}$$. So, I think your definition is a little  incorrect...

Comment: That is just rephrasing what I said.

Comment: you wrote $$A^{\mathsf{T}} = (a_{j,i})_{1 \le j \le n, 1 \le i \le m}$$! Which is incorrect! The reason I wrote in my previous comment...

Comment: Yes, and how does that differ from what you said? The entries are the same, the indices are the same; I simply stated the indices in a different order.

Comment: Actually I think that it's a convention to write $(a_{ij})_{(\text{inequality of row  first},\text{inequality  of column  second})}$

Comment: @PrincessEev Anyhow, I edited my question a bit...